# Copy-paste text among Split Window Buffers

Tags: buffers, copy-paste, window-splitting

Say I have split my main Emacs Window into 2 : `LEFT` and `RIGHT`.

My cursor is currently in `LEFT`. How do I copy some text from `LEFT` to `RIGHT` without going to the `RIGHT` window?

Comment: Personally I just use `C-x o` to jump between two buffers that are open.
On the second `C-x o` you return to the same place you left. Depending on why you don't want to go to the other window you might be able to use my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another opinionated implementation, it assumes 2 windows layout and isn't as sophisticated as `append-to-buffer`, the point is Emacs is very easy to extend.

```el
(defun my-copy-to-next-window (b e)
  "Copy text in the region to next window."
  (interactive "r")
  (pcase (window-list)
    (`(,w0 ,w1)
     (with-selected-window w1
       (insert-buffer-substring (window-buffer w0) b e)))
    (t (user-error "Only works with 2 windows"))))
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks! However, when I have same buffer open in the 2 windows (with cursor at different positions), this fails. Running your command simply copies in the same window (since the other window is holding the same buffer). I need this to work as I have often a very large file opened side-by-side and I am copying text from one region to the other.

Comment: @shivams That's expected, I knew such limitation when I wrote the command, I didn't try to resolve the issue since I won't use the command and I thought it's not very hard (replacing `with-current-buffer` with `with-selected-window` seems working).

Comment: @shivams I just edited the answer to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now this works perfectly as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few relevant commands, though they are not bound to any keys by default. Try `M-x append-to-buffer` to copy the region in the current buffer to another buffer.

See [Accumulating-Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Accumulating-Text.html#Accumulating-Text) in the Emacs manual for details. Note these commands prompt for the target buffer. If you do this a lot with two windows open you could define your own command to look for the other visible buffer and call `append-to-buffer` with that.

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is something you do a lot, I think the simplest solution is to record a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) for copying to the other window.

Press `f3` or `C-x (` to start recording, then `M-w C-x o C-y C-u - C-x o` to do the copying and come back, and `f4` or `C-x )` to stop recording. Then press `f4` or `C-x e` each time you want to copy something.

You may want to tweak the macro to leave the cursor in the other buffer or to move it in a certain way. The point is that you record whatever repetitive action you want, then press a single key to perform it again.

See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) for more information, including how to work with more than one macro, how to bind a macro to a key and how to save macros.

Comment: Using macros is an interesting idea :)

Answer (score 1):

One indirect approach came to my mind. This can be done using `ediff-buffers`. When we run this command, it puts 2 buffers in vertically split windows. Then, using `n` and `p` keys, you can go to the next and previous difference. Then, by pressing `a` or `b`, you can copy-paste difference from one buffer to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You call the buffer that's in the RIGHT window (C-x b) into the LEFT window. You paste what you need into the buffer, and you revert to the original buffer.

No need to change of window, you just change of buffer in the LEFT window.